# Prevent Media Manager popup from loading in a separate window

Tags: fix-my-code, media-manager

I am trying to load the Media Manager when the user clicks on a link. It does load but instead of loading as a popup in the same page, only the popup loads in a separate window/tab. Here is the code I am using.

```
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 570, y: 400}}" onclick="IeCursorFix();return false;" href="http://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;e_name=text" title="Image" class="modal-button">Image</a>
```

Comment: First make sure you load the required js for modals with JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); , then check for js errors.

Comment: Have got the modal JS enabled but still redirecting without any JS errors unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class needed to be 'modal' in this case for it to work.